# Is there a way to check for popBackStack call in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a back stack of a few fragments and I need to know that I have returned to one from another.

Similar to when you have `onActivityResult` I was wondering if you could have a check for `popBackStack()` calls in a fragment?

I call it in another fragment here:

```
@Override
public void postFinished(){
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Anything like this in android java?

Comment: Backstack change listener is only way, as @SHIDHIN.T.S posted answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can add Listener for `BackStackChange` on your Activity page Like,

```
     getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {

                       // Your Code Here

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                        if (fm != null) {
                            int backStackCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
                            if (backStackCount == 0) {


                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You can use `addOnBackStackChangedListener` with `fm.getBackStackEntryCount();` which will give back stack count of fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do in onViewCreated() method:

if (savedInstanceState == null && !mAlreadyLoaded) {
    mAlreadyLoaded = true;

    // Do this code only first time, not after rotation or reuse fragment from backstack
}
Because when android put fragment on backstack, it only destroy its view, but don't kill instance itself, so mAlreadyLoaded will be still true when fragment will be restored from backstack.
```