# Which method is called when returning to a replaced fragment in a tablayout via calling popBackStackImmediate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

#### OK I found out that I am opening/replacing the fragment in another layout element than the one the tablayout is in. Therefore the underlying fragment is never really left if i understand correctly and also no lifecycle methods are triggered.

I have FragmentA inside a TabLayout from which i call:

```
//inside FragmentA
@Override
public void onClickView() {
    activity.replaceFragment(FragmentB.newInstance(), true);
}
```

in replaceFragment the passed fragment is added to the backstack in the transaction and then replaces the fragment

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean doAddToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (doAddToBackStack) {
        String tag = fragment.getClass().toString();
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }

    ft.replace(R.id.mainFragment, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

After that, FragmentB opens, I do my stuff and return via popBackStackImmediate() to FragmentA:

```
//inside FragmentB
@Override
public void onClickBack() {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

and when I go back I need to update something in FragmentA.

According to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11353470/3160493) on the platform when returning to a fragment onCreateView() should be called but that does not work for me. According to the [fragment lifecycle documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) the onCreateView() is only called the first time the UI is drawn which would explain my troubles.

My question is now what lifecycle method can I use or what other approach should I take to execute code when returning to a fragment from backstack?

Comment: What does your `replaceFragment` code actually do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I updated the post with the replaceFragment info

Answer (score 0):

According to the following answer you can add a listener to check when it is being called
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52646588/6468214

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {

                       // Your Code Here

                }
            });
```